# Twig with handlebars js curly braces

Tags: symfony, twig, handlebars.js

I am using twig and handlebar.js with symfony2. I am making handlebar templates in twig file using  tag.

But the problem is both use {{ }} curly braces. So the values used for handlebars are mixed with twig. So on page load exception appears.

Is there any way to use both at the same time.

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 12):

Use the [`verbatim`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) tag.

```
{% verbatim %}
  <ul>
    {{#items}}
      <li>{{name}}
    {{/items}}
  </ul>
{% endverbatim %}
```